# How can I differentiate between a Multivalued Attribute and an Entity?

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

While designing ER Diagrams, how can we differentiate between a Multivalued Attribute and an Entity?

How can we know that, what we are considering as an 'Entity', isn't actually an entity but a Multivalued attribute or vice-versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can distinguish them from their characteristics. Entities are those involved in the system whereas attributes are properties of an entity or, you can say that attributes belong to an entity.

For example, in a Hospital IS, the people involved are Doctor, Patient and Employees. Thus, they are entity. Disease and Medicine are also entity since they are involved in the system. It can be easily defined as Entity because there are relationships among them where Doctor *give* Medicine and Patient *suffers from* Disease.

A Patient may have an Allergy of certain foods. We use the word *have* in here. Thus, Allergy is a multi-valued attribute.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know how to diagram a multivalued attribute, you could start [at this page](http://www.smartdraw.com/entity-relationship-diagram/) and scroll down to multivalued attribute.

If you want to know how to tell a multivalued attribute, it's about the way you analyze the subject matter, and is actually somewhat subjective.  One example that's given is the skills of an employee, because an employee could have multiple skills.  But for this case, it's just as valid to describe a "skill" as an entity, and "skills of employees" as a many-to-many relationship between employees and skills.

Often, when you get down to designing relational tables, you'll end up with the same design either way.